# codefluent: requestcb.auth 404.3 not found

Tags: codefluent

Got SocialEmailLogin 1.0.11.3 from nuget

I get a 404.3 - Not Found on requestcb.auth

That's not weird because it is not in my project. The question is where can i get it? Been looking al over but could not find.

Answer (score 1):

*.auth has to be handled by your AuthCallbackHandler class inheriting from SoftFluent.SocialEmailLogin.AuthCallbackHandler in order to answer to the sociallogin result

In web.config you should have or add in the **handlers** section one mapping of your handler :

```
<add name="SocialEmailLogin" verb="*" path="*.auth" type="XXXX.Security.AuthCallbackHandler"/>
```

Please look at [Example of SoftFluent Social Login Demo](https://github.com/SoftFluent/SoftFluent.SocialEmailLogin/tree/master/SoftFluent.SocialEmailLogin.Demo) that provide a sample AuthCallbackHandler.cs implementation

Comment: So it isn't a file?
Shouldn't that be fixed in the Nuget install also?

BTW yesterday I switched to aspsnippets that works ok for me